# Understanding relation between axis of least and maximum second moment

Tags: moments, computer-vision, derivative, geometry

I was going through computer vision lecture [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_HwkG90Yvw&ab_channel=FirstPrinciplesofComputerVision). You can find the pdf of this lecture [here](https://cave.cs.columbia.edu/Statics/monographs/Binary%20Images%20FPCV-1-3.pdf).

I was trying to understand how orientation of object corresponds to axis of least second moment aka inertia. Its discussed in above lecture video and page 5 to 7 of the monograph.

Below is my understanding:

> [image]
>
> - Second moment of area (aka moment of inertia) for any chosen axis is the sum of the square of the shortest distance r of each point on the object from that axis.
> - Note that as per this definition, intuitively we can understand,
>
>   - at axis $θ_1$, the second moment $f$ (distribution of mass / sum of the square of the shortest distance r of each point on the object from $\theta_1$) is maximum
>   - at axis $θ_2$, the second moment $f$ is minimum
>
> - Also, it turns out that $θ_2$ is the orientation of the elliptical object.
> - Thus, in order to find the orientation of the elliptical object, we need to find the axis of the least second moment.
> - First derivative of mass distribution wrt to axis tilt represents how mass distribution changes. Thus,
>
>   - Positive first derivative represents increase in the mass distribution
>   - Negative first derivative represents decrease in the mass distribution
> - Second derivative of mass distribution wrt to axis tilt corresponds to how rate of mass distribution changes.
> - When the second derivative of the second moment is positive, it's suggesting that as we rotate the object's axis, the rate at which the mass distribution changes (how quickly the mass is moving away from or closer to the axis) is increasing. This behaviour aligns with the concept of an axis of minimum inertia because the mass is effectively spreading out from the axis more rapidly as we rotate it. This suggests that the object is easier to rotate around this axis, making it the axis of minimum inertia.
>
>   - At axis $θ_1$, the second derivative of the second moment is maximum and thus it corresponds to the axis of least inertia / second moment.
>   - At axis $θ_2$, the second derivative of the second moment is maximum and thus it corresponds to the axis of least inertia / second moment.

I believe the least inertia happens when the mass distribution is least. That is why $f''$ is max when $f$ is min at $x=0$.

Bow the lecture says:

> Axis $\theta_1$ of minimum inertia will be perpendicular to axis $\theta_2$ of maximum inertia.

I was expecting maximum inertia i.e. least value of $f''$ to occur at the same value of $x$ for which $f$ is maximum, that is mass distribution is maximum. But this does not seem to be the case. Max $f$ seem to occur at $x<-4$ (or $x>4$), but min value of $f''$ seem to occur at $x=-0.25$ (or $x=0.25$).

What I am missing here?

PS:

- I have take equation for $f$ intuitively: to simulate change in the sum of squares of points on objects from axis. Am I wrong with the intuition?
- You can access above visualization [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/upa53ahjv0).